# Какими Laravel библиотеками можно узнать информацию по IP?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Раньше для этой цели использовал парсинг. Отправлял IP и получал такую информацб как страна, область/стат, город, код города, часовой пояс и т.д. Но парсинг периодически блокируется. Хочу заменить это какой-нибудь библиотекой, которая давала бы максимум информации по IP. 
Посоветуйте что-нибудь. Чем больше информации по IP, тем лучше.

Comment: вот хорошее api: http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp Инфа о них тут: https://www.geoplugin.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
public function authenticated(Request $request){

Log::info('Пользователь прошел авторизацию '.Carbon::now()->toDateString().' с ip адреса: '.$request->getClientIp());

}
```

и не забываем прописать:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

смотрим логи:

```
лог,  находится в storage\logs
```

Comment: @Jurchello если вопрос решил вашу проблему примите его нажав на галочку с лево от вопроса.